# NextJS Sanity - Reference and Array

Tags: next.js, sanity

I have created a two schemas (Product and Categories). The schemas are connected by Reference.

I get the following error message when I try to render "Product.Category". I am able to render other Products attributes i.e., Product.Name.

Unhandled Runtime Error

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_ref, _type, _key}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
const category  = {

name: 'category', title: 'Categorys', type: 'document', fields: [

    { name: 'name', title: 'Name', type: 'string'
     },

     { name: 'slug', title: 'Slug', type: 'slug', options: {source: "name"}
     },

  ] }

export default category ;




const product  = {

name:"product", title: "Products", type: "document", fields: [

      { name: 'name', title: 'Name', type: 'string'
     },

     { name: 'slug', title: 'Slug', type: 'slug', options: {source: 'name'}
     },

    { title: 'Category', name: 'category', type: 'array', of: [
        { type: 'reference', to: [{ type: 'category'}],
        },
      ],
    },

  ] }

export default product ;




import { getProducts } from "@/sanity/sanity-utils"; import product from "@/sanity/schemas/schemaproduct" import Image from 'next/image' import Link from 'next/link'

export const revalidate = 10;

export default async function Home() { const products = await getProducts();

return (   <div>
     <div>{products.map((product) => (
       <div>{product.category}</div>
        ))}
      </div>   </div>  ) }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and make your code readable. In edit mode you can see formatting hints on the right side bar.